# Is it possible to change to a different constructor within a constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have some conditions in my constructor. If the parameter fails those conditions, I would like to use another overloaded constructor instead. Is this possible?

Example code:

```
public Header(byte[] givenData, Utilities.FileType defaultingFileType)
{
    int index = -1;
    if (givenData != null)
    {
        // possibly alter int index here
    }
    if (index != -1)
    {
        // found match, parse givenData
    }
    else
    {
        // no suitable match found, default to given file type
        this = Header(defaultingFileType);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

The line:

```
this = Header(defaultingFileType);
```

is my impossible attempt to change to another constructor. How would I change to another constructor at this point? If I cannot change to another constructor, I'll have to copy/paste the other constructor's code into this constructor at that point. The constructor I would like to use instead at that point is:

```
public Header(Utilities.FileType givenFileType){}
```

Comment: no.  Next question please.

Comment: Is this a class or struct? Structs can assign to this, but classes cannot.

Comment: @mikez This is a class.

Comment: you can extract out the constructors logic and call the method instead

Comment: The standard thing to do then is put the common code a method or move all code into a private constructor that both of them call. Could the other call this one with `this(null, givenFileType)`?

Comment: @mikez No, the single-parameter constructor is the default "make a new one" whereas this two-parameter constructor has the first parameter as data to parse and second parameter as a backup option in case it doesn't parse properly so that the common code can be used to construct a new one instead. I was hoping I could do that by simply switching to the other constructor. It seems a private constructor would work as the best alternative.

Comment: Ah then I would actually make this a static method called `ParseOrDefault` or something similar. That is more consistent with the framework's style. You don't have `new DateTime(string)`, it's `Parse` or `TryParse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not call constructor by another constructor, but you can use one of this solution:
1. create static method and run constructor :

```
public class Class1
{
 public Class1()
 {
 }
 public Class1(param1)
 {
 }
 public Class1(param1,param2)
 {
 }
 public Class1(param1,param2,param3)
 {
 }
 public static Class1 GetNew(param1,param2,param3)
 {
  if(param1 != null && param2!= null && param3!= null)
  {
    return new Class1(param1,param2,param3);
  }
  else if(param1 != null && param2!= null && param3== null)
  {
    return new Class1(param1,param2);
  }
  else if(param1 != null && param2 == null && param3== null)
  {
    return new Class1(param1);
  }
  else 
  {
    return new Class1();
  }

 }
}
```

2-use one Constructor and Create methods:

```
public class Class2
{
 public Class1(param1,param2,param3)
 {
  if(param1 != null && param2!= null && param3!= null)
  {
    Method1(param1,param2,param3);
  }
  else if(param1 != null && param2!= null && param3== null)
  {
    Method1(param1,param2);
  }
  else if(param1 != null && param2 == null && param3== null)
  {
    Method1(param1);
  }
  else 
  {
    Method1();
  }
 }
 public void Method1(param1,param2,param3)
 {
 }
 public void Method1(param1,param2)
 {
 }
 public void Method1(param1)
 {
 }
 public void Method1()
 {
 }
}
```

Comment: I think the second approach, and what the comments recommended, is what best matches my coding approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch to a different constructor from within the body of a constructor. If this is something that you need, your best bet will be to either switch to private constructors and use a static method to invoke the constructor or to use a factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use default values, you can use syntax like that:

```
public Header(byte[] givenData, Utilities.FileType defaultingFileType = [DEFAULT_VALUE])
{
...
}
```

This will only work from .NET 3.5 and the default value must be constant.

If you find this insufficient, I think the best way to solve this is static method, that is used to create an instance of this class. You can even set the constructor to be `private` if you want to avoid inappropriate use of the class.

In addition, you can also create some private functions that handles the fields that the condition is about. Then just call this function with different parameters each time.

Comment: To clarity, if the `byte[] givenData` is invalid, I want to construct the object instead using the `defaultingFileType` which is provided to say, "if it didn't work out, just use the default constructor with this value instead." That's `Header(defaultingFileType)`. Is it possible to use a static method to set an object's properties?